# Android Unity black screen on game start up

Tags: unity, c#, android, google-play

Squishing bugs on my first game currently, came across a problem I'm not sure what could cause.

When the game is launched there is simply a black screen before even the unity logo shows up, the duration is about 5 seconds. Checked on 2 devices: S6 and 1st gen Moto X, the duration is about the same.

The scene loaded on start-up is a simple menu with almost no logic, just some buttons.

I am using the Unity Google Play plug-in, could it be somehow connected with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by it being a development build with script debugging, a normal build works as expected.

Comment: A dev build with script debugging on should work fine. There's something weird going on.

Comment: Check if Unity override the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat hilarious yet very real situation:

My blackscreen was caused by the fact that I had a canvas or camera with the "EditorOnly" tag. Removing this tag made the objects work correctly during the actual builds, and the black screen was no more.